# Ext HDD won't mount

Tags: external-disk, mount, hdd

I have several Ext. HDD attached via USB to my iMac. Turning the mac on this morning three of the four drives mount no problem. (all in the same ext power / usb tower) but one drive does not mount.

I went into Disk Utility and the drive shows up there but it's child shows up greyed out. When I select the child it shows that I can mount it but when I actually hit the mount button nothing else happens. The button does not show unmount but stays as mount.
[image]

It shows the child as being all yellow (other) but its far from full.

Can anyone help ?

Many thanks all

Is this what you need ? If not let me know, thanks for your help.

[image]

```
Device Identifier:        disk3s2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk3s2
   Whole:                    No
   Part of Whole:            disk3
   Device / Media Name:      E Drive

   Volume Name:              

   Mounted:                  No

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Journal:                  Unknown (not mounted)
   Owners:                   Disabled

   Partition Type:           Apple_HFS
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Disk / Partition UUID:    BB43A59F-CA7A-407B-A912-89CA19F5C00C

   Total Size:               999.9 GB (999860912128 Bytes) (exactly 1952853344 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:          External
   Removable Media:          No
```

Like that ?

It didn't mount :o(

```
Last login: Thu Apr  7 08:40:46 on ttys000
Pauls-iMac:~ pual$ diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk3
One or more volume(s) failed to mount
Pauls-iMac:~ pual$
```

Comment: Could you please post the information of `diskutil list` and `diskutil info /dev/diskxsz` where `diskxsz` is the disk device identifier (left column lowest field in DU) of said partition `Untitled` to your question?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking if not let me know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: try `diskutil info /dev/disk3s2` instead. Also, you can format the terminal output as code by indenting plain text four spaces *or* selecting all code and clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry is that helpful ?

Comment: Yep, great. From this information I can conclude that your drive is formatted correctly, and should not have any problems mounting. Ironically, it's having problems mounting. I would suggest you try `diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk3` and see if that gives any errors.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry No Luck

Comment: did it mount, or did it throw an error?

Comment: It came back with : 
One or more volume(s) failed to mount

Comment: Okay, try `diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk3`.

Comment: All seems ok there :diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk3
Started partition map verification on disk3
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Checking the partition map size
Checking for an EFI system partition
Checking the EFI system partition's size
Checking the EFI system partition's file system
Checking the EFI system partition's folder content
Checking all HFS data partition loader spaces
Checking booter partitions
Checking Core Storage Physical Volume partitions
The partition map appears to be OK
Finished partition map verification on disk3

Comment: This makes no sense.. The file system seems to be in order. Have you tried switching the USB ports? Alternatively try `diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk3s2` and see if that brings up anything

Comment: Yer thats what I thought, I will give your suggestions a go now.

Comment: I can only specify whole disk it says so using disk3 it then warns that the partition map might erase disk3s1. Is it safe to continue anyway ?

Comment: In regards to using my other USB ports my other three disks seem to work ok with the current USB port. Maybe I should move the disks position in the ext caddy ?

Comment: Yes, it's safe. `disk3s1` is the EFI partition. As per the USB ports, have you checked the connectors of the faulty disk itself? I wouldn't suspect it's a connectivity issue though.

Comment: @njboot I feared so, but if verifyDisk can be maintained I would think it has a bit of life left in it

Comment: Guys you've been very helpful. I'm going to sort another HDD and see if I can get someone to retrieve the files from the disk3. Thanks again cheers

Comment: Pretty much the same issue. Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Pretty much the same issue. Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is a clear cut hardware issue. If you cannot mount the volume, even after trying to do so forcibly, it’s almost always due to physical failure of the hard drive disk.

You can test with varied USB connections (different cable, then different hub) to eliminate the alternatives and confirm the diagnosis. Best of luck.